# Connecting two computers to one monitor to livestream

Tags: vga, dvi

I've seen multiples posts about this topic arguing that you can connect two computers to a single monitor using for one DVI port and for the other VGA for example.

If I've understood well in this case just similarly as a TV you can select which computer controls the monitor by simply switching between them with your monitor. But in our case (live streaming something) we would live to have PC1 managing the monitor, meaning that PC1 controls what is displayed on the monitor (showing slides for instance) and PC2 only gathering the display of the monitor to live stream it with a dedicated software? Is this possible with a simple configuration PC1 plugged into monitor with DVI and PC2 plugged into monitor with VGA? What configuration do we have to make? And if not possible, can a device/gear make it work?

Comment: If I understand well, you mean that PC1 sends the video and both the monitor and PC2 receive the video, right? In that case, you can't do it by plugging PC2 to the monitor, you have to equip PC2 with a dedicated device called "Capture card" or "Acquisition card" (I don't know the actual English name) and plug it directly to PC1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nathan ! Yes I think that it but corresponds to my idea I want to the PC2 to gather the image displayed on the monitor by PC1 so yeah it is like saying that both the monitor and PC2 receive the video sent by PC1. Thanks for the track I will investigate on it to be sure it can fulfill my needs :). But what if I need this monitor, for example in our case we would like to livestream a speaker and the slides he présents, this speaker needs to see the slides broadcasted on the monitor to know at what point he is in his presentation?

Comment: If you need both you may need an additional VGA splitter (a device that takes 1 VGA input, and sends it to 2 VGA outputs simultaneously). Some acquisition cards have one built in. Another option: Have the your speaker use the video feedback on the acquisition or streaming control panel on PC2.

Comment: OK thank very much Nathan indeed I've started looking at capture cards and I think that they will answer our needs. Thank you again and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

no, the monitor is a receiving device meaning u cant capture what is being displayed on it and send it to another device. plus u connect 2 PCs to one monitor that means u will have 2 channels on the monitor, In ur case dvi and vga or most likely would be dvi and hdmi. so the monitor can receive only from each PC thro whatever port and display in the according channel and will never send to any of them 
***but u can use a video camera*** connected to the 2nd pc and filming whatever displayed from the 1st PC and then u can live stream 
if u have surveillance system that would works or u can even get an ip camera connected thro network and staright live stream without the need to the second pc

Comment: i wd hv upvtd ths f u hdnt usd so mny bbrevs n omtd pncttn n paras.

Comment: Can you please translate that from text speak to English?

Comment: Thanks very much Ahmed, very clear ! Yes indeed processing this way won't work that's why I'm now looking for gear like suggested above, for example splitter or capture cards :) Have a nice day !